# Autoupdate SQL query results in Microsoft Word document on open

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

Is it possible to have Microsoft Word 2010 automatically update SQL data which was inserted into a document by using Microsoft Query on file open?

When using insert database function in Word, after configuring your datasource and creating your SQL query, the data is inserted as a table into currently open document. Before the data gets inserted, you get to choose if the data should be pasted as FIELD.

If field is selected, the data comes up in fields (like when you do insert - date/time) and by rightclicking on the fields and choosing "update field" in the context menu, the data should automatically updated. This does not work because Word prompts for datasource once more, so having reports based on SQL queries which require no user interaction is not achievable.

Is VBA (and doing the manual labor of creating a table and filling out the cells through vba) the only way to achieve zero user interaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input. I ended up writing this VBA:

```vb
Private Sub Document_Open()
'wipe the document
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Delete

'prepare drivers
Dim cn As New ADODB.connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.recordset

'setup document header
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "CRONUS AB - All employees report"
ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Style = "Title"

'prepare header for table
Selection.TypeText "First name" & vbTab & "Last name" & vbTab & "Job title" & vbCrLf

'create connection and execute SQL query
cn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "trusted_connection=yes;DATABASE=Demo Database NAV (5-0)"
rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee]", cn

'iterate through recordset and print out results to the document
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Firstname = rs![First Name]
    Lastname = rs![Last Name]
    Jobtitle = rs![Job Title]

    Selection.TypeText Firstname & vbTab
    Selection.TypeText Lastname & vbTab
    Selection.TypeText Jobtitle & vbCrLf

    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'convert text to table and apply table style
ActiveDocument.Range.ConvertToTable Separator:=wdSeparateByTabs
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Style = "Light Shading"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result using by various means:

- Include Excel tables in Word.
- Use VBA or VSTO as described above. There are various articles described already how to add code.
- A (free) version of Invantive Composition as an add-in to Word (but I work there).
- Maybe even RTF generation on a Samba share that automatically fills the RTF using the magic statement. Sorry, it is really called that way! See [Samba book](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch08_02.html).

The option chosen depends on some variables I can think about:

- Roll out to how many client PCs?
- Size in pages of the filled out document, such as 1 page or 1.500?
- Controlled environment or PC's somewhere else in the world using a web frontend?
- Number of document templates to be set up?
- Support for both 32 or 64 bit Word?
- Are database drivers available at all PC's?
- May all users access the database (credentials)?
- How frequently does the result of the SQL change?

I can further pin down options when you provide some more background or an example of what the document should look like?